# Loading an AAC / MP3 file "manually"

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, mp3, decoding

For an application I'm creating, I need to be able to read AAC and MP3 files and get the waveform data (not play it directly, I need to manipulate the data before playing).
Ideally, I should be able to read any MP3/AAC file out there (VBR, different bitrates, etc), or at least anything that could potentially show up in iTunes.

This last point is very important, as Chuck commented. I assumed iTunes would be MP3s, I didn't know they used AAC. In essence, I must be able to read anything that is in iTunes.

What approach do you recommend me to use?
What kind of libraries are out there?

This is for a commercial application that will run on Windows, written in C# 3.0. I can use Open Source libraries, but nothing with a license that will make me release my source code later.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hope you realize that a good chunk of iTunes music is AAC rather than MP3.

Comment: One further caveat: Until recently, all songs bought from the iTunes Store were encrypted Apple-proprietary DRM. Nothing except QuickTime and the DMCA-violating JHymn can decode those (and I'm not 100% positive about the Windows version of QuickTime).

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm, and i'm guessing there is no "export to MP3" feature in iTunes, right? (or in another software, but something that's not illegal)

Comment: For the DRM-protected files, the only legal way to remove the FairPlay protection (besides paying a 30¢-per-track upgrade fee) is to burn the tracks to CD and reimport them as MP3.

Comment: Wait!
That 30c per track fee sounds doable!
I'll have to start playing with this thing.
Thanks for your help! Sorry for my newbie naiveness.

Comment: All iTunes Store songs these days are DRM-free, though. It's just old ones that people didn't pay to upgrade that would be a problem. You might just be able to tell users their iTunes Store songs have to be iTunes Plus.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been incredibly useful. Could you please put up an answer saying this, so I can mark it as accepted and give you the points? (even though you didn't answer my question, you answered another much more vital one that I didn't know I had).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [mpg123](http://www.mpg123.org/) which is [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) licenced.

There's also [MAD](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/), which is GPL but a commercial license can be negotiated.

For AAC there's [FAAD2](http://www.audiocoding.com/faad2.html), but it is GPL. Not sure if other terms are available. Another source of enquiry might be checking the sources and licences used in this [list of AAC software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding#Software) on wikipedia.